# How can I find points of intersection with *two* moving variables?

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

This may be a stupid question but bear with me.
Previously in my project, I used the below formula to find the points of intersection of various sets of 2 lines (feeding in for example a set of values for prem1, dc1, coins1, and then for prem2, dc2, coins2 for the second line).
The result, 'bill_at_supercede', told me at what value the lines would intersect.

```
bill_at_supercede <- (prem1 + dc1 - prem2 - dc2 - coins1 * dc1 + coins2 * dc2) / (coins2 - coins1)
```

What I want to do now is answer the same question, but with two different 'moving variables' -- one for 'bill', which is the same value called 'bill_at_supercede' in the above, and one for er_bill_at_supercede.

My question now is, at what pairs of (bill, er_bill) will the lines intersect?

I tried modifying my first formula as below, but I don't know how to define 'bill' as a moving variable instead of feeding it a value like I fed in a value for prem1, prem2 etc.

```
er_bill_at_supercede <- 
((bill- dc1) * coins1 + prem1 + dc1 - (bill - dc2) * coins2 - prem2 - dc2) / (er_coins2 - er_coins1)
```

I am not sure if the question is stated clearly but if it isn't, let me know and I will try to give a better description or any more information.

Thank you very much for suggestions!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a maths problem, rather than a programming problem, and the formulas required for solving the maths are not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this as a system of equations, the answer will fall out.  Set the equations equal to each other and solve.  For example, if the two equations are y = x^2 and the other is y = x, you solve x = x^2 and find it has two solutions - {0, 1} which is also the intersection of the lines.  Matrix operations can solve as well.